# Google Load balancer behavior during slow clients

Tags: java, tomcat, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

**Scenario setup**
1. let say i have a tomcat running on a google compute.
I have a simple hello world servlet like below

```
1. public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
2.  throws ServletException, IOException {
3.  sysout("request IN")
4.  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter().println(VERY_LONG_JSON_200KB);
5.  sysout("request OUT")
6. }
```

**Cases:**

Now if i hit this servlet directly using the machine ip, using a very slow client (2 KB download speed)
My worker thread in tomcat will be stuck for about ~100 second at the `println(VERY_LONG_JSON_200KB);` line. As `VERY_LONG_JSON_200KB` does not fit into the socket buffer and the thread as to wait.

In this case my tomcat thread is stuck due to slow client connection.

**NOW**

Instead of directly connecting to tomcat machine ip. I added a Google load balancer in front of the tomcat.
And now using by slow client, i connect to tomcat through load-balancer.
And now the `println` line get executed in `1 ms`.

This means that load Balancer consumed the response from tomcat quickly and then serving it to client.
This is good as my tomcat thread is not stuck.

**Question**
Now the question arises is that How many requests will load-balancer consume quickly and serve as per the client pace.

For eg: Let say 1000 concurrent Slow client comes in, will the Google load balancer will consume the response from tomcat quickly for all 1000 request.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here [1]: "(...)It supports 1 Million+ queries per second with consistent high performance and low latency.".

So yes, Google Cloud Load Balancer will be capable to request quickly the response from the tomcat backend up to 1 Million request per second.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/